# How do I bypass an htaccess rule?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&subPage=$2
```

It works great but I want to be able to take a url such as:

```
http://mysite.com/admin/somefolder/index.php?action=test
```

and have it bypass the rewrite rule and behave as it normally would.

I'm not too sure what the regex would be. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Your above rule will NOT match `/admin/somefolder/index.php?action=test` anyway so no need to bypass that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Rewrite condition to limit the application of the rule.

I think this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
```

Haven't messed with mod rewrite in a long while, so make sure you test.